# Fazer extend de lista a outra lista

Tags: python

Bem eu tenho duas listas de listas, lista1 e lista2:

```
lista1 = [['carlos','10','cenouras','carro','agora'],['duarte','34','couves','bus','agora']] 

lista2 = [['11:30', '12:00'],['13:00', '13:30']]
```

O que eu quero é criar uma nova lista com os primeiros 2 elementos de cada lista dentro da lista1, ficando: `listaNova = [['carlos', '10'], ['duarte', '34']]`

A seguir, a cada lista dentro da listaNova quero adicionar uma lista da lista2, ficando:

```
listaNova = [['carlos', '10', '11:30', '12:00'], ['duarte', '34', '13:00', '13:30']]
```

Por fim quero adicionar o ultimo elemento da lista1:

```
listaNova = [['carlos', '10', '11:30', '12:00','agora'], ['duarte', '34', '13:00', '13:30','agora']]
```

O que já tenho é isto:

```
listaNova =[]

for i in lista1:
   nomes = i[:2]
   listaNova.append(nomes)
```

Mas agora não sei como fazer extend do resto..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode correlacionar os elementos das listas `lista1` e `lista2` através da função [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip). Além disso, você pode concatenar listas usando o operador `+`. Então, se você criar uma nova lista - usando [compreensões de lista](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compreens%C3%A3o_de_lista) - em que cada elemento é `e1[:2] + e2 + e1[-1:]` você consegue o que quer:

```
>>> lista1 = [['carlos','10','cenouras','carro','agora'],['duarte','34','couves','bus','agora']]

>>> lista2 = [['11:30', '12:00'],['13:00', '13:30']]

>>> listaNova = [e1[:2] + e2 + e1[-1:] for e1, e2 in zip(lista1, lista2)]

>>> listaNova
[['carlos', '10', '11:30', '12:00', 'agora'], ['duarte', '34', '13:00', '13:30', 'agora']]
```

(Note que eu usei `e1[-1:]` em vez de simplesmente `e1[-1]` porque eu quero uma *lista* com um elemento, e não só o elemento)

Se você quiser fazer "por extenso" (i.e. usando loops, `append` e `extend`), ficaria assim:

```
listaNova = []
for e1, e2 in zip(lista1, lista2):
    item = []
    listaNova.append(item) # append acrescenta um item na lista

    item.extend(e1[:2]) # extend acrescenta os itens do argumento na lista
    item.extend(e2)
    item.append(e1[-1]) # como é um único elemento, pode usar append
```

Por fim, se você quiser evitar o `zip`, pode fazer um loop normal, sobre os índices das listas (cuidado, certifique-se que as listas têm tamanho igual):

```
listaNova = []
for i in range(len(lista1)): # i vai de 0 a "tamanho da lista" - 1
    item = []
    listaNova.append(item)

    e1 = lista1[i]
    e2 = lista2[i]

    item.extend(e1[:2])
    item.extend(e2)
    item.append(e1[-1])
```

Mas note como o código fica extenso, enquanto o primeiro método faz a mesma coisa usando uma única linha de código... À medida que você dominar esses conceitos (principalmente o de compreensão de listas, uma das características mais poderosas da linguagem) acostume-se a usá-los no lugar de construções mais verbosas, quando apropriado.

Comment: Não me consegue explicar isso de uma maneira mais simples, usando o append e o extend ?

Comment: enganei-me foi numa coisa, á editei como queria. na listaNova final queria que ela ficasse só assim: `listaNova = [['carlos', '10', '11:30', '12:00','agora'], ['duarte', '34', '13:00', '13:30','agora']]`

Comment: @StinRose Claro, editei minha resposta com duas formas alternativas. A opção com compreensões é bem mais concisa, entretanto, considere dar uma estudada nela e seu código ficará bem mais "enxuto". :)

Comment: Obrigada ! :) era isso mesmo